# Matlab - mark a particular value on x-axis

Tags: matlab

I would like to mark a specific value, say 1.2345 on the x-axis, perhaps emphasize it with a bigger dot or a circle or something similar. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this depends on what you're plotting. If you're plotting a function you could do:

```
>> fplot(@sin, [0 2])
>> hold on
>> plot(1.2345, sin(1.2345), 'ro')
```

[image]

If you're plotting a vector, then use [INTERP1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/interp1.html) to interpolate the data to your target x value:

```
>> x = 0:.1:2;
>> y = sin(x);
>> figure
>> plot(x, y, '.-')
>> yi = interp1(x, y, 1.2345)

yi =

         0.942913175277465

>> hold on
>> plot(1.2345, yi, 'ro')
```

[image]

Comment: +1. @Viktor: if you really want the 'x-axis', you'd use `plot(1.2345, 0, 'ro')` in this example.

Comment: Combine this with `set(gca, 'XTick', [0 1.2345 2])`.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set the `XTick` and `XTickLabel` [properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html) of the axes.

`set(gca, 'XTick', [0 1 1.2345 2]);`

You might also want to draw a vertical line:

`line(x0*[1 1], get(gca,'YLim'))`